# Using HTTPS for web app development in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, https

I am working on a web app that requires to have HTTPS on the client
side . The problem with using eclipse is I can't use HTTPS while in
development mode.

Is there a way we can have the eclipse dev server support HTTPS?

Thanks,
Achit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible with GWT 2.3: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.3/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/README-SSL.txt

Comment: Confirmed that adding "-server :ssl" to the program arguments adds HTTPS functionality for local testing.  Brilliant!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS typically isn't enabled on development environments.  This is usually a deployment aspect for production and less of a development concern.

Comment: Actually, that's not accurate.  HTTPS has some different behviours than http, and building in http and expecting it to "just work" when deployed on https can lead to major issues.